# Automatic select only member in the object list

Tags: bash, powershell, rest

Is there a way to automatically address/select the only member in a object?
In my case the 3rd level member jobf can vary. But on that level it will always only have one member.

```
### get aeObject ###
try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "$client_id/objects/$($i -replace "#","%23")" -Headers $header
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message "$($_.Exception.Message)"
    $Error[0] | Format-List -Force
}

### modify JSON and import it ###
$JSON = $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSON.data
if ($JSON.data.jobf.general_attributes.time_zone) {
    $JSON.data.jobf.general_attributes.time_zone = "$TZ"
}
else {
    $JSON.data.jobf.general_attributes  | Add-Member -Name "time_zone" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "$TZ"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFvk.png)

Comment: How about `$JSON.data = $JSON.data.jobf`? (or is it the _name_ of `jobf` that can vary)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Get-Member` to iterate the members at the third level, then filter out the noise and select the name of the first (and only one) member.

```
# Get the third level single item (eg: jobf, jobx, etc)
$Job = ($JSON.data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -First 1).Name

# Instead of "jobf", we use the value stored in $Job
if ($JSON.data.$Job.general_attributes.time_zone) {
    $JSON.data.$Job.general_attributes.time_zone = "$TZ"
}
else {
    $JSON.data.$Job.general_attributes  | Add-Member -Name "time_zone" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "$TZ"
}
```

**References**

[Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.2) - Gets the properties and methods of objects.